# Textarea focus very simple code not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have written following code.

```
$("input,textarea").blur(function () {
        debugger;
        var val = $.trim($(this).val());
        if (val != "") {
            if (containsHTMLTags(val) == true) {                 
                $(this).css({ "border": "1px solid red" });
                $(this).focus();    
            }
        }      
    });

    function containsHTMLTags(str) {
        if (str.match(/([\<])([^\>]{1,})*([\>])/i) == null)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
```

Code checks the value of all input and textarea control with regular expression for html input. If regex fail I want to focus on control, I don't know why **$(this).focus();** this line of code not working.

Please help!
Thanks

Comment: make a jsfiddle please

Comment: please don't make a jsfiddle. Use inline snippets.

Comment: @Amit didn't get you, inline snippet

Comment: Just FYI: your regex can be minimized to `/<([^>]+)>/`. Do not use nested quantifiers, that may lead to serious issues. Please provide an [MVCE (minimal complete verifiable example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Move `$(this).focus();` outside the inner if clause. because this statement right now is executing only when `containsHTMLTags()` returns true.

Comment: Look [here (snippets)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers).

Comment: Is this line working as expected (meaning called as you expect it, at least): `$(this).css({ "border": "1px solid red" });` ??? If ya, on which browser `focus()` isn't working?

Comment: Here a [JSFiddle with your code](https://jsfiddle.net/aforni/77az25b2/). The code seems to work: when a string matching the RegExpr is found, the input/textarea get focus. In this way the user cannot move to another input/textarea. Isn't this the behaviour you want?

Comment: @ dreamweiver, Yes I want it should focus only if containsHTMLTags return true. I want to focus on text area if it contains any html tag that's why I am checking for all input and text area controls within the form

Comment: @cachet.net But, is the `form` submited or what? You have to provide minimalistic sample in question itself replicating issue

Comment: @Andrea, fiddle is working but in my web form it is not working. I don't know why.

Comment: @A.Wolff, yes it is assigning border to text area, line is working but next line $(this).focus(); is not working. I am not submitting form. I want if user enter any value and on focus out if it contains html element, text area border should be red and focus should be on control, user should not move to any other control till he/she removes the html tags.

Comment: @cachet.net On which browser are you testing it (works for me on chrome)? Are you binding any jq `focus` handler to these inputs (preventing e.g default behaviour)? Does it change anything using native DOM method: `this.focus();`?

Comment: @A.Wolff I have tried on both IE7 and Chorme - not working. I need to check for preventing default behavior. According to me it should work.

Comment: All Members, After focus out if control contains html controls if changes html like <textarea name="12512" rows="2" cols="20" id="12512" class="expand" style="width: 25%; height: 19px; overflow: hidden; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border: 1px solid red;"></textarea>. It is clear that style has been applied to control but focus is not working.

Comment: @cachet.net It works as expected for me on chrome, so your issue comes from somewhere else...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92225/discussion-between-cachet-net-and-a-wolff).

Comment: @cachet.net , you can check the answer below which works as of your desire

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after spending 2 hours resolve the issue. All controls of web form generates from database so id of each controls is primary key of table basically it's number. Jquery recognize id should start with character. Just read on internet.

Here is the working code I am using

```
   $("input,textarea").blur(function () {
        var val = $.trim($(this).val());
        //console.log(val);
        if (val != "") {
            if (containsHTMLTags(val) == true) {
                debugger;
                $(this).css({
                    "border": "1px solid red"
                });
                var s = $(this).attr("id");
                document.getElementById(s).focus();

            }
        }
    });

    function containsHTMLTags(str) {
        if (str.match(/([\<])([^\>]{1,})*([\>])/i) == null)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
```

Many thanks to all members who helped me.

Thanks

Comment: Down votes are always welcome but please mention the reason what's the reason. If reason will not be there, how we will improve next time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your regular expression to this:

```
str.match(/([<|>])/gi) == null
```

```js
$("input,textarea").blur(function () {
    var val = $.trim($(this).val());
    if (val != "") {
        if (containsHTMLTags(val) == true) {
            $(this).css({
                "border": "1px solid red"
            });
            $(this).focus();
            
        }
    }
});

function containsHTMLTags(str) {
    console.log(str.match(/([<|>])/gi))
    if (str.match(/([<|>])/gi) == null) 
        return false;
    else 
        return true;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea></textarea>
<input/>
```

Comment: It is applying style to control after validating html tags if contains, no issue with regex. only problem with $(this).focus();

Comment: @cachet.net _only problem with $(this).focus();_ i don't get it. isn't it working demo?

Comment: i guess it is checking if you have any `< >` signs in the input/textarea you can't loose focus from it. right.

Answer (score 0):

No sooner blur event is fired , the focus event gets triggered for next element , you can run your codes in that handler

You can do it by a little trick--

```
$("input,textarea").blur(function () {
    var val = $.trim($(this).val());
    console.log(val);
    if (val != "") {
        if (containsHTMLTags(val) == true) {
            $(this).css({
                "border": "1px solid red"
            });
            var r=$(this);
            r.next().on('focus',function(){ //bind a event to get focus again
            r.focus();
            r.next().off('focus'); //unbind it
            });


        }
    }
});
```

**LIVE** https://jsfiddle.net/mailmerohit5/z400jx87/